# Visually check for image duplicates and corrupted images in PHP or Python

Tags: php, python, image-processing, duplicates, corrupt

I'm hoping to find some help here regarding image processing.

I'm not familiar with Python, though I am with PHP.
Though I heard that Python is "better" for image comparison, resizing, etc.

Now, I'm looking to create a program that will compare an image against a MySQL database
in order to find similar images. 
If the similarity is higher than a certain amount (percentage?), it'll be flagged as a possible duplicate.

Next to that, I'm also looking to create a program (which will run before the dupe-check) that should check if an image is corrupted / incomplete.

I've looked through StackOverflow, but only found answers from 2008 / 2009,
and I figured that there's probably a more efficiënt or more effective way of doing things by now.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and if you happen to reply to my issue, thanks in advance. :)

**edit:**
I've noticed how the [eyeBuy SDK](https://sites.google.com/site/imagecomparison/) "combines edge detection, color, intensity, and contrast information into a single string". Would this be a good solution to my duplicate image detection?

Comment: I'm using a modified version (that supports imagefromstring) of http://robert-lerner.com/imagecompare.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, after reading about it:
`bad uses are trying to see how similar pictures are of the same item at different light levels, angles, perspectives, etc.`
which is actually what I'm trying to achieve.

I've got a database of 500,000+ images of various resolutions, and in this database I have multiple duplications and corrupt images, which I'm trying to filter out.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find how similar photos are in different light, angle, perspective requires hell of a lot algorithm which, I think, is not necessary in your case. There is no simple way to do so.

However if you have different images that you resized or modified little bit, the script *Artjom Kurapov* mentioned will help you very much as a starting point. If your database also contains *duplicates* I would go first with *MD5* comparison before trying anything else.

You should use a simple database that you calculate `md5` hash, record to database and search in the database for a match, otherwise for each file you have to go through the whole database which will drastically increase the process time.

You will also need to create some kind of serialization from the script that you can keep records if you don't want to process the whole database of images for each file.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've looked further into the script that was suggested by _Artjom Kurapov_, and I will see how it holds up in an environment with 500,000+ images. I'm already using an md5-check, so there _should_ be no duplicates when it comes to that.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, an algorithm that can deal with different perspectives is going to be very difficult. It is the focus of a lot of (academic) research.

For a simple start, you could have a look at the [Python phash](http://www.phash.org/).

A simple DCT based algorithm that is reasonable resilient to noise and scale would do the following:

1. Convert image to grayscale
2. Crush your image down to thumbnail size, say [32x32]
3. Run the two dimensional Discrete Cosine Transform
4. Keep the top left [8 x 8], most significant low frequency components
5. Binarize the block, based on the sign of the components
6. Result is a 64 bit hash

And a variant on this theme would be

1. Convert image to grayscale
2. Optionally re-size to a predefined size.
3. Partition the image in a fixed number of blocks
4. Determine the global mean
5. Determine the local mean per block
6. For the hash, write out a 1 or a 0 per block, pending if the local mean was larger or smaller than the global mean.

Comment: Ooh, I must've overlooked pHash, thanks! For now it would be sufficient to just look at the scale and actual content, so I'd have a start.